# Unable to find column with logical name hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

I have table where to 2 columns join another relations. I was tried join this with `@JoinColumns` but i getting error `Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name CLASS_ID in table item_sub_class`
I looked in h2-console and in table item_sub_class i see column class_id. Look screenshot
[image]

This is my relations code from Item class

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Item implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String description;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "class_id")
    private ItemClass itemClass;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name= "subclass_id",referencedColumnName = "subclass"),
    @JoinColumn(name= "class_id",referencedColumnName = "class_id")

    })
    private ItemSubClass itemSubClass;
    private Long sellPrice;
//getter and setters

}
```

And ItemSubClass

```
@Entity
public class ItemSubClass implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @JsonProperty("subclass")
    @Column(name = "subclass")
    private Long subclass;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "class_id")
    private ItemClass itemClass;

//getters and setters



}
```

Some one can explain what is bad and why this relation throwing me error? This is possible to fix this?

Comment: Does the ITEM_CLASS tabel have ID column? What is the Primary Key in the table? I see no key on your screenshot.

Comment: @StanislavL have ID(class) this table only have name and id and relations to items and subclasses. I Added more code.